# Cocuhdb a fit for a query like this?

Tags: couchdb

I have been looking for an escape from GAE as the datastore does not support a lot of the things I want to do with it.

So I have looked at CouchDB (among others) and I really like the REST interface and the hosting option I found at Cloudant.

But for all my googling and reading any docs I could find, I still am not sure if it is a good fit.
So I come here in the hope that someone might have more insight.

I write web apps and a lot of the projects I want to do will involve a query that looks like this:

Find all entries that are within a user-input-lat/long bounding box and where start-time is less than user-input-time-1 and end-time is greater than user-input-time-2 and has all tags in user-input-list-of-tags.

Thats not even pseudocode, but I hope it makes sense anyway.

I am not just looking for a "You cannot do that in CouchDB". Some kind of explanation and perhaps something like "If you can live without the tags then you can do this:"

I would like to use the Cloudant service so GeoCouch is apparently out of the question, but they do something that should work like lucene, but does that mean the queries are slow?

As you can tell, I am a bit confused here, so just do your best to straighten me out and I'll be greatfull :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not mentioning the tags (which in itself is already a problem), what you describe is a multi-dimensional query : you have several "coordinates" (lat, long, start-time, end-time) and provide a range for each of these coordinates.

On its own, CouchDB cannot perform multi-dimensional queries at all — you only get single-dimension queries across one coordinate.

Tags certainly are possible, but it depends on whether you need documents that have at least one tag in the list, or documents that have *all* tags in the list. The first case is easy (run one query per tag using the bulk API), the second might require excessive amounts of memory (if a document has N tags, it needs to emit 2<sup>N-1</sup> tag-sets in order to match all possible tag combinations involving it, so you should place an upper bound on either the number of tags in a document, or the number of tags in a query).

Lucene does allow multi-dimensional and keyword-based queries, though I cannot vouch for their performance.

Comment: I got what I was looking for. Just a nudge in the right direction. Cloudant search seems to be just what I need. Now I just need to figure out if "social-auth" can only be oauth or if I can use openid as well, but thats another question.